# Trying to display json data from wikipedia nicely

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I am having trouble formatting the JSON data into html I have tried various methods and would just like a bit of help or pointing in the right direction. The example I've been playing with is 'apple' and here is what I'm currently getting, this is the second element of the apiResult array [(pic)](http://prntscr.com/diy4lq).

In my ajax call the action I'm using is opensearch as I was advised to do that but I have seen a lot of people using query. Here is my [codepen](http://codepen.io/johnthorlby/pen/NbOPeg?editors=1010) if anyone needs to take a look for themselves. Thanks for any help, I appreciate it.

Here is my html:

```
<div id="main">
  <div id="title">
    <h1>Wikipedia searcher!</h1>
    <hr />
  </div>
  <div id="content">
    <h3 id="random"><a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:Random" target="_blank">Click here for a random wikipedia page</a></h3>
    <form>
      <div class="row" id="searchDiv">
        <div class="col-xs-4">
          <h3>Search for a wikipedia article:</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-4">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="search" name="search">
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-4">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="searchBtn">Search</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
    <ul id="theData">
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Here is my JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#searchBtn").click(function() {
    var $theData = $("#theData");
    var title;
    $.ajax({
      url: 'https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php',
      data: {
        action: 'opensearch',
        limit: 10,
        namespace: 0,
        search: $("#search").val(),
        format: 'json'
      },
      dataType: 'jsonp',
      success: function processResult(apiResult) {
        var html = "";
        $theData.html("Displaying search results for " + apiResult[0]);
        apiResult.shift();
        console.log(apiResult[0].length);
        $.each(apiResult, function(i, apiResult) {
          for(var x = 0; x <= apiResult[0].length; x++)
            {
            html += "<div class='result'>";
            html += apiResult[i][x] + "<br>";
            html += "</div><br>";
            }
        });
        $theData.append(html);
      }
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: could you define what you meant by nicely?

Comment: So you output the results as an unordered list of items. Are you looking for how to style that list using CSS? Are you looking to display the results in a table?

Comment: I also noticed that inside your <ul> instead of <li> items you have <div> elements. Unordered lists are only supposed to contain <li> items as direct children https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/ul

Comment: Sorry for not saying this is the [example](https://codepen.io/FreeCodeCamp/full/wGqEga/) so the information is all in one space. There should be more than the one result in the screenshot but I'm having trouble with it

Comment: I just edited my js and now it is outputting [this](http://prntscr.com/diykzt) can't figure it out